# Maven openshift plugin - kubeconfig file in custom location

Tags: openshift, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using maven-openshift-plugin 1.9.1 with docker-local profile in java project to upload whole project as docker image to OpenShift.
I have kubeconfig file in default location : ~/.kube/config with my own token.

**Is it possible to set custom location for kubeconfig file ?** Our plan is to build project in CICD pipeline and we will have kubeconfig file within project with service account token to access OpenShift.